# Variational derivative of $F_w(f) = \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_1 \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_2 f(x_1)w(x_1,x_2)f(x_2)$

Tags: derivatives, calculus-of-variations

I am starting to work with functional derivatives. In Density functional theory an advanced course by Engel and Dreizler they have the example of the functional in the title of this question. The variation of the functional can be calculated to be

$$\delta F_w = \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_1 \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_2 w(x_1,x_2)[(f(x_1)\varepsilon \eta(x_2) + f(x_2) \varepsilon \eta(x_1) + \varepsilon \eta(x_1) \varepsilon \eta(x_2)] $$

The Taylor Expansion around $\varepsilon = 0$ is

$$ \delta F_w = \frac{dF(f + \varepsilon \eta)}{d \varepsilon} \bigg|_{\varepsilon = 0} \varepsilon + \frac{d^2F(f + \varepsilon \eta)}{d \varepsilon^2} \bigg|_{\varepsilon = 0} \varepsilon^2= \\= 
 \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_1 \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_2 w(x_1,x_2)(f(x_1)\eta(x_2) + f(x_2) \eta(x_1)) \varepsilon + \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_1 \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_2 w(x_1,x_2)2 \eta(x_1) \eta(x_2) \varepsilon^2 $$

By the definition of functional derivative I get that in the first term I need to isolate $\eta(x_1)$, this can be done by rewriting it in the following way

$$\frac{dF(f + \varepsilon \eta)}{d \varepsilon} \bigg|_{\varepsilon = 0} =   \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_1 \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_2 (w(x_1,x_2) + w(x_2,x_1))f(x_2)\eta(x_1)$$

Which means that the first functional derivative is

$$ \frac{\delta F}{\delta f(x_1)} = \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_2 (w(x_1,x_2) + w(x_2,x_1))f(x_2)$$

So far, this agrees with the textbook, however there is something I do not understand in the second derivative, and it might be just some simple algebra issue. We have that

$$ \frac{d^2F(f + \varepsilon \eta)}{d \varepsilon^2} \bigg|_{\varepsilon = 0} = \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_1 \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_2 w(x_1,x_2)2 \eta(x_1) \eta(x_2)$$

From the definition of the second variational derivative I conclude from the above that

$$ \frac{\delta^2 F_w}{\delta f(x_1) \delta f(x_2)} = 2 w(x_1,x_2)$$

However the textbook writes that

$$\frac{\delta^2 F_w}{\delta f(x_1) \delta f(x_2)} = w(x_1,x_2) + w(x_2,x_1)$$

I get that (unless there is something I am not seeing)

$$\int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_1 \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_2 w(x_1,x_2)2 \eta(x_1) \eta(x_2) = \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx1 \int_{y_1}^{y_2} dx_2 (w(x_1,x_2) + w(x_2,x_1)) \eta(x_1) \eta(x_2) $$

However, $2w(x_1,x_2) \neq w(x_1,x_2) + w(x_2,x_1)$ unless $w(.,.)$ is symmetric, so my solution to the second derivative differs from the one in the textbook. This might be just some simple algebra I am not seeing, what am I missing?

Comment: First off, your Taylor series is missing a $\frac{1}{2}$ on the $\varepsilon^2$ term and your FOILing added an extra $2$ on its $\varepsilon^2$ term (these errors, of course, cancelled each other out). Second off, how do you go from $$\frac{d^2}{d\varepsilon^2}\mid_{\varepsilon=0}  = \iint_{I^2} w(x_1,x_2)\eta(x_1)\eta(x_2)$$ to saying $\delta^2F/\delta f(x_!) \delta f(x_2)=w(x_1,x_2)$? Note that different kernels $w$ can determine the same functional; in particular $2w(x_1,x_2)$ and $w(x_1,x_2)+w(x_2,x_1)$ determine the same functional, so why call the density one and not the other?

Comment: Also, notice if you find the $\delta/\delta f$ of the expression you already have for $\delta F/\delta f$ you get $w(x_1,x_2)+w(x_2,x_1)$.

Comment: I see the 1/2 mistake but I do not know what you mean with "your FOILing added an extra 2". About your second point, the definition of the second derivative I am working with (the one in the mentioned textbook) is
$$\frac{d^2 F(f + \varepsilon \eta)}{d\varepsilon^2}\biggr|_{\varepsilon = 0} = \int dx_1 dx_2 \frac{\delta^2 F(f)}{\delta f(x_1) \delta f(x_2)}\eta(x_1)\eta(x_2) $$
So I think your doubt in your second point follows from this definition. Different kernels giving the same functional, why not use one and not the other? I seem to get different answers depending on which one I use

Comment: As regards your second comments, I did miss that point, that might be the answer? I should use a kernel consistent with the functional derivative of the first derivative?

Comment: What you just gave **cannot** be a definition of the second functional derivative (at least not alone), since the kernel is not well-defined by the functional! (Unless you stipulate *symmetric* kernels...)

Comment: I see, https://cds.cern.ch/record/1383342/files/978-3-642-14090-7_BookBackMatter.pdf here is the textbook, page 407 has the definition and page 408 the example. Is there perhaps something about the definition of the functional or the kernel that I missed?